# Click Dropdown Button Using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to click the drop-down button in a tweet and then click on "Embed tweet" option using Selenium Web Driver.

[this tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hhQ.png)

I found these codes online and trying to implement but the 3rd line doesn't work:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90");
driver.URL= "https://twitter.com/TheScaryNature/status/1170560743516692480";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='']")).Click();
```

But it doesn't work. I'm beginner. Please help.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Just saying it doesn't work is a little less...

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks for the reply. I get this message- 'no such element: unable to locate element'

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons (as far as I can understand):

1. You are trying to click before the element has appeared correctly on the webpage. In this case, you can wait till the element is actually appeared on the webpage using wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitsec));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@id='']")));
element.click();
```

2. It is possible that the element you are trying to click is in a frame, then you have to switch to that frame(let's say your frame name is investigationFRAME):

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(investigationFRAME);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitsec));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@id='']")));
element.click();
```

You are trying with wrong xpath please give a try to the following code:

```
IList<IWebElement> tooltip= driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='IconContainer js-tooltip']/span[@class='Icon Icon--caretDownLight Icon--small']"));
tooltip.Click();
```

Comment: Did you check for the frame?

Comment: Can you post the URL of the webpage on which you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the button by this code:-
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-0']")).click();

After button click you can click on Embed Tweet:-
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Embed Tweet')]").click();

Comment: Hello, I get this error-
'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='menu-0']"}

Comment: Hello, could you please share the element details , so that i can validate it.

Answer (score 0):

`By.Xpath` is used as a css selector. As not every element has an ID, and seems to me that the drop down menu doesn't have one on twitter, you can try using

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='embed-link']/button[@class='dropdown-link']"))
```

`//li/button` means `li > button` (button inside a li element)

[Twitter embed button looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4gxH.png)

Comment: Hi, I get this error-
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='embed-link']/button[@class='dropdown-link']"}

Answer (score 0):

**First wait to element appears**

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//button[@id='menu-0']//span[@class='Icon Icon--caretDownLight Icon--small']")))

**Then**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='menu-0']//span[@class='Icon Icon--caretDownLight Icon--small']")).click